# Show $\sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{\log(n) + 1}{n + 1} = O\left(\log(N)^2\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, inequality, asymptotics

I am not good with inequalities or big-O notation. Here is my attempt:

It suffices to show that $\sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{\log(n) + 1}{n + 1} \leq \log(N)^2$. We have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{\log(n) + 1}{n + 1} &\leq \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{\log(n) + 1}{n}\\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{\log(n)}{n} + \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{1}{n}\\
&\leq \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{\log(n)}{n} + 1 + \log(N)
\end{align*}

I'm not sure if I'm making the right moves, but at any rate I'm stuck. Thanks.

Comment: You're making the right moves; now bound $\ln(n) \le \ln(N)$.

Comment: @DominikKutek grazie, i believe you get a bound of $\ln(N)^2 + 2\ln(N) + 1$, which is $O(\ln(N)^2)$, so i guess that's that. thank u

Comment: Yes, exactly something like that.

Comment: You are in the right track. I added something for your curiosity and I hope that you will enjoy it.

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Answer (score 1):

*Just for your curiosity.*

Since the integral is simple
$$\int \frac{\log (n)+1}{n+1}\,dn=\text{Li}_2(-n)+(\log (n)+1) \log (n+1)$$ the simplest form of [Euler-MacLaurin summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) gives
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\log (n)+1}{n+1}=C+\log (N)+\frac{1}{2}\log ^2(N)+\frac{3 \log (N)+5}{2 N}+O\left(\frac{\log (N)}{N^2}\right)$$

For this level of summation
$$C=\frac{4487221}{19353600}-\frac{\pi ^2}{12}-\log (2)$$

For $n=1000$, this gives $29.49540$ while the exact summation gives $29.49502$.

The relative error is smaller than $1$% when $n \geq 10$,  smaller than $0.1$% when $n \geq 20$,  smaller than $0.01$% when $n \geq 81$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $x \mapsto \frac{\log(x)+1}{x}$ is decreasing for $x \ge 1$, therefore the sum can be estimated above by an integral:
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{\log(n) + 1}{n + 1} \leq \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{\log(n) + 1}{n} \le 1 + \int_1^N \frac{\log(x)+1}{x} \, dx \\
= 1 + \log(N) + \frac 12 \log(N)^2 = O\left( \log(N)^2\right)  \, .
$$